# Get JSON data from sniffing Apple push notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have got a wireshark trace of an apple push notification.
But i only have some kind of binary data. Is there a way of retrieving the JSON data with this packet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection to APNS is encrypted with SSL, so you would need the private key used to establish the connection.